# API request with Svelte returning object in DOM

Tags: javascript, api, loops, svelte, svelte-3

I'm struggling to understand why my loop is displaying this:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

I tried many things with fetch and axios but it ends the same way

Here is my Svelte component:

```html
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  let results = [];

 const fetchYoutubeList = async () => {
    const searchQuery = 'mySearch';
    const maxResults = 10;
    const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_YOUTUBE_API_KEY;
    const apiBaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_BASE_URL;

    await axios.get(`${apiBaseUrl}`, {
      params: {
        part: 'snippet',
        maxResults: maxResults,
        q: searchQuery,
        type: 'video',
        key: apiKey
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        results = response.data.items;
        console.log(results);
        console.log(typeof results);
      });
  };
</script>

<section>
  <button
    class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded mt-2"
    on:click|once={fetchYoutubeList}
  >
    Bring me joy
  </button>

  <div>
    <ul>
      {#each results as item }
        <li>
          {item.id}
        </li>
      {/each}
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here the results of my logs:
[image: console logs]

I think I missed something but I can't find what, so if some of you have an idea I would be glad if you can debug me

Thanks

Comment: Have you logged the `results` array to look at the shape of your data? without seeing an example of your results there's not much to say except `item.id` seems to refer to an object.

Comment: `response.data` is a json, then my `results` is an array but when I log the type is logging `object`

Comment: Yes I see that, but arrays *are* objects (`typeof [] === 'object'`) and can also hold objects. Try logging a single item (`console.log(results[0]);`)

Comment: Oh ! I found my mistake here (it's Friday evening  )... My `item.id` is an object hence the display (weird api returning an object in `id` field ^^)

Thanks, you make me find my mistake 

Comment: I had a feeling. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE]- Solution

Thanks to @pilchard, I found my mistake here.

I was trying to loop through an object because my `item.id` was an object (weird by the way ^^), so everything is ok I manage to do my loop normally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).